# Update App Configuration Android

Tags: android

what is a best way to implement configuration feature in androids application for example my application access to specific web URL and in feature this URL may be change to something else how can i change the URL in application whenever the URL is change ?

Comment: The original URL within you APP should not be changed. But you could make the URL redirect to somewhere else as you wish.

Comment: Can the users change the URL? or is a predefined user-based configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The best that you can do is use a property file loaded at the startup from a server somewhere, and from there read all the properties that you need.

But obviously you have to tell the app where to get this file, and that has to be "sticked" in the app itself!